# Asynchronus File Upload with StateServer Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, stateserver

I want to implement Asynchronus File Upload.

I've tried `ajax:AsyncFileUpload` control. It's working fine only with InProc Mode.

But I'm using StateServer Mode.

Any help from anybody?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Debashis

Answer (score 1):

As the Darin point the issue with the control you are using, I think you need to change your control choice, use AJAX uploaded and check URL, you will find here lot of uploading AJAX based control

http://ajaxuploader.com/Demo/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncFileUpload` control tries to put an `HttpPostedFile` instance into the session. This works fine with InProc session but will fail with out of process session because this requires the class to be marked with [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx). Long story short: you can't use anything else than `InProc` with the `AsyncFileUpload` component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- [AsyncFileUpload only support InProc session mode](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=24854)
- [ASP.NET File Upload with Real-Time Progress Bar](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti_1.html)